# Is [All] a level aswell as a member

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

Looking at the diagram for our ClientId hierarchy I see a pattern that is repeated in most hierarchies:

[image]

If I expand `All` then every member of that hierarchy is included - is `All` a level as well as a member?

Comment: As far as I know, [All] is a member

Comment: @michele why can you expand [All] and then see all the members of that level/hierarchy? - this doesn't seem to be a normal member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All, is the parent member of all the members of an attribute whose propertey "IsAggregatable" is set to TRUE.

ALL is also a level that contains the All-member(s).

Depending what you are using the following statements can return a reasonable result or an Error, so I would it is good to know the difference between ALL and All

```
Dim.hier.[All].children
Dim.hier.[(All)].children
Dim.hier.[(All)].members
Dim.hier.[ALL].children
Dim.hier.[ALL].members
```

Hope this clarifies some things

Tom

Comment: +1 this is an interesting answer Tom: I'd never seen this ALL compared to All ... will test your permutations against one of our cubes