# Mdx , All and All Members differences

Tags: ssas, mdx

In MDX what is the difference between

```
[Period].[Period Name].[Period Name].ALLMEMBERS 

and

[Period].[Period Name].ALL
```

are these statement same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ALLMEMBERS` is actually a function in the `MDX` language. This function returns a set of members. Slightly unusual a function being tagged on the end of a string but `MDX` is unusual.

MSDN reference to this *function*: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144768.aspx

`[All]` in the context you have given is a single member - the `All` member. Most hierarchies have one of these members. The most general form of this member I believe is `[(All)]`. Here is an example of it's use against `AdvWrks` cube:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[(All)] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];

SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[All] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

I think a hierarchies `all` member can be renamed to something more descriptive such as `All Dates` in which case you would need to use either `[All Dates]` or `[All]`

I previously asked a question specifically about the All member:
[Is [All] a level aswell as a member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316940/is-all-a-level-aswell-as-a-member)

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not. `ALLMEMBERS` means all axis members, for instance: period1, period2, period3 .., including all periods in 1 member : All

So, `[ALL]` member means all periods. For example, you can calculate [Measures].[Total Sales] for each date in month or for **all** dates in month. This the case when you need just [ALL] member to do it

If you want to get just members, without `ALL` member, you should use: `[DimA].[LevelA].Children`